# How to have typescript determine non-safe destructuring scenarios?

Tags: typescript, object-destructuring

Example code below would lead to a destructuring error because it'd try to destructure `undefined`. How can we prevent typescript from compiling successfully for this kind of unsafe destructuring code?

```js
interface IOptionalObjectProperties {
  prop?: {
    nested?: {
      val?: string;
    };
  };
}

const object: IOptionalObjectProperties = {};
const {
  prop: {
    nested: { val }
  }
} = object;
console.log(val);
```

leads to runtime errors like

```
/test.ts:24
} = object;
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nested' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/test.ts:24:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1043:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1046:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at main (/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:225:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:512:3)
```

**EDIT**

**ANSWER**
Using `strictNullChecks` as `true` in config detects these scenariosl.

Comment: your code does not even compile correctly with strictNullChecks.

Comment: It's not accepted in the playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkAOZgHsRwA26ARgFYQJgAKUum0OEAzsgN4BQyymdmA-AC52XbshAtIAEyEixYgG5FZzMFFABzANyjuAXx36dejhwT5VyXOUphhGbHgLEbVWvUbAWyALzsDZhZgcjx8wpzyEqoQUuHISoTIJvocer5WrmA65iDMuIQQAHSEuBoAFAkAlDpAA

Comment: Is the answer to this question just "use `--strictNullChecks`"?  I'm inclined to close this as non-reproducible without some more information from OP

Comment: @jcalz yeah seems like that is it, strictNullChecks which seem to be enabled by default on the playground. It complies without that which led to this question. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `strictNullChecks` option can flag scenarios like this.